# Java socket behavior when closing in multithread enviroment

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

What happens when a java socket is closed, while another thread either blocks on a read or is trying to write to the output stream?

Comment: The blocked thread throws `SocketException: socket closed`, if you're lucky, but it isn't well-defined. You shouldn't have to do this.

Comment: @EJP which goes to say that this is a very good question.

Comment: @MikeNakis Not really. It's not the real underlying question. The real question is about how to structure things so it isn't necessary. I've never had this problem.

Comment: I should clarify that I was here talking about `java.net.Socket`. If you close a `SocketChannel` the blocked thread will incur an [`AsynchronousCloseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousCloseException.html), and this is well-defined.